# Is there a way to hide html element when printing a PDF

Tags: javascript, laravel, dompdf

I want to hide "View Details" anchor tag from PDF when it gets print. Is the are a way to hide html element from PDF when printing. Iam using DOMPDF laravel package from generating pdf's i got a solution https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onafterprint.aspbut not working in my case.

```
**@media print {
       // Hide unwanted HTML:
       …
    }**
```

the above given code snippet is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 'Print Stylesheet'.

Just a few CSS rules and you're done:

```
@media print {
   // Hide unwanted HTML:
   …
}
```

Comment: tried but not working it works on html pages but not working when printing a pre- generated pdf.